# How do I delay screen update?

Tags: javascript

Ok, im updating it and make it as easy as possible to read.

Im wanting to have the word scrolling from right to left (in my full code im listening to keypress and remove the first letter in the word if it matches).

When I do the code below, the text only shows up once on the left side with coordinate 0. As mentioned i want it to flow from right to left. Thanks a bunch!

```
<script src="http://koda.nu/simple.js">
        const word = ["T", "e", "s", "t"];
        let x = 200;
        let y = 200;

        while (x > 0) {
        clearScreen();
        setInterval(text(x, y, 40, word.join("")), 5000);
        x--;
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi! The question is very open, and has a lot of "noise" in it (code & facts that are not relevant). Please supply a "Minimal, Reproducible Example" (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to ensure you ask a high-quality question (an others think so too ;)).

Comment: To try to answer: You are most likely looking for a timeout of some sort (wait some time until processing continues). In JavaScript, there is the `window.setTimeout` function: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: By reformulating your question according to the "Minimal, Reproducible Example" guideline, you would have likely found this (as there are many similar questions out there). It helps to think about the problem in a structured way, and saves a lot of time to yourself and to others.

Comment: Please don't use `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` (or W3 Schools as a reference for that matter) - these are not good choices as they don't provide precise enough timing. The only option for animation of a game is [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) coupled with the [performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance)

Comment: Here is a great article that describes my last point: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/

Comment: I decided to go with the SetInterval() option, but I dont get it to work. It doesnt flow, just pop up at the end (x = 0).

Answer (score 3):

you can try to use setTimeout/setInterval(for repeating) which is built-in javascript.
more details:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: I updated my code with that, see above, it doesnt work.